# Allow certain files to be delivered only from a certain URL - Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, hosting, web-hosting

I'm using Apache 2.4 to host a Django application.

I have a public directories with some videos. They can be seen when using a certain website as they're loaded from a public directory but I don't want people to make a script to batch download all my videos because that could hinder my server.

[1] The video should work in a link similar to http://example.com/43. 43 is the id and can be any number.

The videos reside in something like http://example.com/media/videos
Which internally would be something like /var/www/someapp/media/videos

Is it possible to only make those videos available when requested from [1] ?

Answer (score 0):

The Alias directive supports establishing a URL path that is internally mapped to a file system directory:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

So try

```
Alias / /var/www/someapp/media/videos
```

To mitigate bulk downloading, the videos should be named in a way that is not guessable.

It may also be desirable to disable directory indexing:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```